# Contour Integration with rectangular path

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

$$\int_C \frac{z^2}{z^2 +4} dz$$ where $C$ is the rectangle with vertices$ −2,2,−2 + 4i,2 + 4i$ traversed in the anticlockwise direction.

Anyone know how to do this question? i've tried using cauchy integral formula but i'm not sure on how to do this particular integral as it has a rectangular path.

Comment: do you know the residue theorem?

Comment: cauchy integral formula poses no condition on the shape of the contour. You need only to find what is inside it.

Answer (score 3):

Within the rectangle, there is only one singularity at $\,z=2i$, thus suppose $\,\gamma\,$ is a small circle around $\,2i\,$, then by $\textbf{Cauchy's integral Formula}$, we have:

$$\int_C\frac{z^2}{z^2+4}\,dz\ =\ \int_\gamma\ \frac{z^2\left/(z+2i)\right.}{z-2i}\,dz\ =\ \left.2\pi i\frac{z^2}{z+2i}\,\right|_{\ z=2i}\ =\ -2\pi$$

Answer (score 1):

There is only one singular point inside the rectangle. It is $2i$. Therefore according to residue theorem
$$\int_C\frac{z^2}{z^2+4}dz=2\pi i\ \text{Res}\left(\frac{z^2}{z^2+4};\ 2i\right)=-2\pi.$$

Comment: is it possible to complete this using the cauchy integral formula?